# How to optimise Google/FB/GA javascript in website for PageSpeed Insight

Tags: pagespeed

PageSpeed shows 97/100 and is asking for Leverage browser caching for the following.

https://accounts.google.com/…8rb1vn78o04oj.apps.googleusercontent.com (10 minutes)

https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js (20 minutes)

https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js (30 minutes)

https://apis.google.com/js/rpc:shindig_random.js?onload=init (30 minutes)

https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)

Read through multiple posts on GA where folks have suggested to serve these scripts ourselves and have a cron to update the scripts.
Is this what Google or FB would prescribe?

Suggestions to solve this for the above scripts?

Comment: In the jQuery world, we can use an ajax call with cache set to true and load the google and facebook JS SDK. 
When the ajax call is done, we can use the gapi or FB handle to initialise the library with the client credentials. This way the library is now fully ready to perform login related work.
With this I was able to remove the dependency of including these JS files in the head section of the html. This meant little more faster loading and a near perfect google speed score. I m still hunting for google analytics.